# GeoWebCache not deleting expired/discarded tiles from _gwc_in_progress_deletes_ folder

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Is it OK to 'force' delete folders/files from GeoWebCache's

**_gwc_in_progress_deletes_**

folder?

I have a folder (zoom level) with several subfolders each having tens of thousands of tiles that have not been deleted for about a month now (& with no detectable changes/no errors in geoserver error log).

GeoServer Version 2.12.2

GeoWebCache version 1.12.2, build 1.12.x/8e746f758aabae3ab832c30757de6fafa4c39d0a